# How can I purge Scratch's configuration and / or re-install it?

Tags: code, apps

Scratch hasn't worked for the last two months, I can't edit files:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for correction. I'm new here :) i'll improve my next questions!

Comment: Can you supply some more information? Which part of the process fails? Can you open files? Is it saving that's the problem? Is it a file you own or a system file? Is there any output when you run scratch from Terminal?

Comment: @DanielForé Scratch works fine when I open an existing file, but the problem is only when I try write a new file (click on "+" button)

Comment: @DanielForé I reported a rather similar bug some days ago: https://bugs.launchpad.net/scratch/+bug/1471053. I use the terminal to attempt to generate a new file in Scratch and I get the same empty window as a result. See bug entry for more details.

Comment: Fixed. Solution in other thread [link][1]


  [1]: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1241/cant-open-a-new-tab-or-new-file-on-scratch

Answer (score 5):

You can reinstall apps / packages with apt-get with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall scratch-text-editor
```

Comment: Doesn't work yet :( [screenshot](http://i.droppic.net/ayNd1_gJieo)

Comment: @AlonsoCN that's working I think... Click the folder icon.

Answer (score 4):

As it isn't working currently, a reinstall might not fix it.

To remove all config files (so Scratch settings and last opened files will be gone) as well, use these commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge scratch-text-editor
sudo apt-get install scratch-text-editor
```

Comment: I think it should be `scratch-text-editor`, possible typo.

Comment: I'm sorry, but --purge flag doesn't work. I still can't write a new file with Scratch :(

Answer (score -2):

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall pantheon-files
```

It will solve your problem