# Why I can't open files / pantheon-files sometimes?

Tags: pantheon-files

When I click on files in plank nothing happens.

I tried run it throw terminal and get following output:

```
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 09:12:19.775418] Application.vala:155: Files version: 0.2.2
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 09:12:19.775509] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 3.16.0-43-generic
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 09:12:19.779318] Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-Amn1kcn0AB: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt
Failed to register: Zeitüberschreitung wurde erreicht
```

(Zeitüberschreitung wurde erreicht [DE] = Timeout was reached, Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt = Connection rejected)

What does this means?

Comment: Does it happen only to "Files" ? or to any icon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, this is based on research (and I fear my answer will be rather technical), but your problem seems to be caused by `dbus`, a way for applications to communicate with other applications (so-called inter-process communication, you can learn about it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus)). People had this problem in the past with Nautilus (the GNOME file manager) as well (there is a [bug report on the GNOME bug tracker](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=727622) about that problem, unfortunately it does not hold any solution).

So, is there any solution / answer to this? Not really, as we cannot pin down the application that is not responding via `dbus` (at least not without diving deep into the source code and start debugging). My **assumption** is it is related to `gvfs` (a virtual filesystem, providing access to files from various sources, for example via `SMB`, `NFS` or other protocols). If you have external file sources (for example any network location) in Files and the problem persists, you could try to remove these network locations.

Additionally, if the problem persists, you should open a bug report on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files), so the developers can try to track it down. If the problem does not persist, something went wrong (this does happen sometimes, it's hard to track down those hiccups), but everything should be fine, at least after a reboot.

Comment: Your assumption is probably right. I added some network-shares via CIFS in my fstab.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling `Pantheon-files` might help you fix this. You can report your issue **[here](https://launchpad.net/pantheon-files)**, run Files using `pantheon-files -d`, `-d` is for debug mode. Copy the result in your terminal and paste it in your report bug.

If you want to reinstall Files follow this 
[How can I purge Scratch's configuration and / or re-install it?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/229/how-can-i-purge-scratchs-configuration-and-or-re-install-it/230#230)
, in your case the package name is `pantheon-files` instead `scratch-text-editor`

Comment: I've had this error a couple of times before. Usually after a clean install and I have to wait till I get updates from elementary to a higher version of Freya for it to be fixed. Your answer helped me fix it faster. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem with an NFS share on a server that is not always on. Pantheon-files wants to connect to the same locations as when it was last used, if that location is not available then pantheon-files fails to start. My syslog showed repeated attempts to contact the NFS share and pantheon-files doesn't seem to time out. A work around is to open a terminal and run pantheon-files with a path that does currently exists. eg :

pantheon-files /home/$USER

which should then open pantheon-files in your home directory.

Comment: wolud be great if a bug is opened in Launchpad about this problem, and with your info a fix can be made for pantheon.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files

Comment: I've raised a bug report as requested. https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1602144