# Can't open a new tab or new file on scratch

Tags: release-freya, code

I can't open a new tab or new file in Scratch. Nothing happens when I click on the + icon and the following image occurs when I close all documents and select "New File".

[image: Screenshot demonstrating the issue]

Running scratch from the command line and selecting a new file gives me the following on terminal:

```
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 09:56:27.534393] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 3.19.0-25-generic
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 09:56:27.535770] Settings.vala:158: Loading settings from schema 'org.pantheon.scratch.saved-state'
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 09:56:27.612347] [Gtk] gtk_header_bar_pack: assertion 'gtk_widget_get_parent (widget) == NULL' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 09:56:27.612392] Scratch will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 09:56:27.706954] file /build/scratch-text-editor-JxlBhk/scratch-text-editor-2.2.0~r1522/src/MainWindow‌​.vala: line 421: uncaught error: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado (g-io-error-quark, 1)
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 09:56:27.707004] Scratch will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 09:56:27.707044] [Gtk] gtk_action_set_visible: assertion 'GTK_IS_ACTION (action)' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 09:56:27.707070] Scratch will not function properly. 
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 09:56:27.707235] file /build/scratch-text-editor- JxlBhk/scratch-text-editor-2.2.0~r1522/src/MainWindow‌​.vala: line 421: uncaught error: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado (g-io-error-quark, 1)
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 09:56:27.707270] Scratch will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 09:56:27.709947] SplitView.vala:180: WelcomeScreen shown succefully
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 09:56:27.713487] Settings.vala:158: Loading settings from schema 'org.pantheon.scratch.plugins.folder-manager'
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 09:56:27.713872] MainWindow.vala:472: create 'unsaved' directory: /home/bpantoja/.local/share/scratch-text-editor/unsaved
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 09:56:27.713949] file /build/scratch-text-editor-JxlBhk/scratch-text-editor-2.2.0~r1522/src/MainWindow‌​.vala: line 473: uncaught error: Erro ao criar o diretório: Permissão negada (g-io-error-quark, 14)
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 09:56:27.713983] Scratch will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 09:56:29.189314] SplitView.vala:188: WelcomeScreen hidden succefully
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 09:56:29.191560] SplitView.vala:126: View added succefully
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 09:56:29.191781] file /build/scratch-text-editor-JxlBhk/scratch-text-editor-2.2.0~r1522/src/Widgets/Do‌​cumentView.vala: line 103: uncaught error: Erro ao abrir arquivo "/home/bpantoja/.local/share/scratch-text-editor/unsaved/Ficheiro de texto de 2015-08-12 09:56:29": Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado (g-io-error-quark, 1)
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 09:56:29.191834] Scratch will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 09:56:30.724841] file /build/scratch-text-editor-JxlBhk/scratch-text-editor-2.2.0~r1522/src/Widgets/Do‌​cumentView.vala: line 103: uncaught error: Erro ao abrir arquivo "/home/bpantoja/.local/share/scratch-text-editor/unsaved/Ficheiro de texto de 2015-08-12 09:56:30": Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado (g-io-error-quark, 1)
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 09:56:30.724916] Scratch will not function properly.
```

Comment: Could you check if source tree extension is enabled? Enabling it removes tab navigation for me

Comment: How are you opening Scratch, via its icon or using the terminal command?

Comment: It seems like you've changed the theme, and it's possible that's over-riding the hit-area for the `+`. Could you try reverting to default and try then? Also, repeat for the graphics driver, disable and retry?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is due to [a permissions bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/scratch/+bug/1467564) that occurs when the first time you've run Scratch is as a privileged user. You end up with a directory in `~/.local/share/scratch-text-editor` that you don't own.

To fix this issue:

1. Make sure you don't have any unsaved files in Scratch when run as root (with the `sudo` command). This fix will delete those files.
2. Open Terminal and use root permissions to remove the directory.

   `sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/scratch-text-editor`
3. Open Scratch as your own user (do not use the `sudo` command)

After this, you should no longer encounter the issue. In general, you should not run graphical applications using the `sudo` command since you can encounter these types of issues.

Comment: @BrunoMiranda Can you set your system language to English and then paste the output with a service like [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)? It sounds like there are still permissions issues, but I don't understand Portuguese very well :)

Comment: @BrunoMiranda please add these details to your question instead of here in the comments.

Comment: @BrunoMiranda Ah sorry it looks like probably the whole directory is owned by root. I've updated my directions to delete the whole directory and not just the "unsaved' folder

Comment: Hi Daniel,
Sorry about the mistakes creating the question and the output in portuguese. Deleting the hole directory solved the issue.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Hey, this does not work.  any help