# Can't launch Code via alias

Tags: code, text, editor

I installed Code (the new Scratch) via the instructions [here](https://github.com/elementary/scratch). I also created an alias in my .bashrc file to launch it for purposes of running as su:

```
alias code = 'io.elementary.code'
```

Unfortunately the alias does not work. And I can no longer launch Scratch via the terminal (errors out). Therefore I can no longer edit text files in su. Sure I can install GEdit or run VIM or whatever, but I don't want to use those.

Assistance please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the spaces between the equals sign.

So change:

```
alias code = 'io.elementary.code'
```

To:

```
alias code='io.elementary.code'
```

Comment: that works! Thank you. Any idea how to use sudo -i in conjunction with my alias?

Comment: You might want to use pkexec (`alias code-sudo="pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY io.elementary.code"`) instead, as using sudo with scratch is [known to cause problems](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1241/cant-open-a-new-tab-or-new-file-on-scratch/1250#1250). I don't know if this applies to Code. This will ask you for your password though.

Comment: I mentioned running code with sudo and the devs recommended running with -i to reduce issues. I just hate terminal based editors :) I'll give your recommendation when I get home. thanks!