# code text editor problem in elementary os juno

Tags: release-juno, code

I have another problem but with the code editor this time it does not let me create a new tab 
[image]
even when I right click and click new tab nothing happens I tried uninstalling it and installing it again but the problem is still there I can't write anything literally 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the solution for your problem

[Can't open a new tab or new file on scratch](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1241/cant-open-a-new-tab-or-new-file-on-scratch)

> To fix this issue:
>
> 1. Make sure you don't have any unsaved files in Scratch when run as root (with the sudo command). This fix will delete those files.
> 2. Open Terminal and use root permissions to remove the directory.
>
>    `sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/scratch-text-editor`
> 3. Open Scratch as your own user (do not use the sudo command)

---

Scratch is the old name of Code

With Code the command should be: `sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/io.elementary.code`

Comment: how do i open scratch using terminal @Sebastian

Comment: Scratch is the old name of Code (Sorry I asumed you knew), the current command is `io.elementary.code`. Why you need it?

Comment: ty sebastian i just changed sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/scratch-text-editor to                                                              sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/io.elementary.code again ty for the help i appreciate it

Comment: If it worked then mark it as answered

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue several times both on Juno and Hera. And usually it worked fine after a fresh install. But I just came to see that *sometimes* even after a fresh install, it doesn't open. So here is the solution:

Open Terminal

`sudo su`

`cd /home/user/.local/share/io.elementary.code/`

(here the "user" is your username on eOS).

`chmod 777 unsaved/`